# Breaking out of attribute in double quotes

Tags: web-application, xss, html, bbcode

I have a piece of code that allows for

```
[url]someurl[/url]
```

BB-Code and replaces it with

```
<a href="someurl">someurl</a>
```

It takes two precautions to prevent XSS.

1. It replaces `<`, `>` and `"` using a simple `str_replace`.
2. Uses a regex to detect `javascript:` and `data:` protocol handlers.

Since browsers decode the attribute value before further interpreting it, you can get around the regex check by encoding the URL using  `[url]&#x6A ... [/url]`.

So I get:

```
<a href="javascript:alert(1)">javascript:alert(1)</a>
```

Long story short: I want more than a steenkin attribute tage (who would click a link looking like that?!)

Can I somehow encode my `"`, `<`, etc. so it won't be replaced by the `str_replace` but still be interpreted in the context of HTML?

Comment: I think this question belong to SO

Comment: I agree this should be on StackOverflow since you're asking how to code something in a particularl language.  I flagged it as off-topic, hoping a moderator can migrate it.

Comment: It is related to security, er4z0r asks how to bypass the described filter to run javascript code.

Comment: @DinuSmădu - Asking how to encode it is a programming question not a security question.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe the question is not well formulated. I understood that the question is how to encode in order to bypass the filter.

Comment: Excatly. Dinu is right. This is _not_ just about encodiing.

Comment: @Ramhound DavidStratton F.Hauri, this is not a programming question. The question isn't "how to encode", it's "what encoding works". I.e. it's not about what lines of code to write, it is about "what should the code do", i.e. security requirements.

Answer (score 7):

A blacklist approach will always be flawed.  For example,  under internet explorer you can use the `vbscript:` URI to execute vbscript code.  There are also ways of encoding `javascript:` to bypass this check.  There have been a large number of itunes exploits that rely upon the `itunes:` URI to exploit itunes from the browser.  This is just two examples,  but really there could be any URI handler registered on a target system.

I would run this though a htmlencode routine to encode all quote marks and angle brackets. The benefit of this is that the URL could legitimately contain quote marks without being damaged. This is because the browser will automatically perform an html-decode of all attribute values as they are loaded.  Then I would enforce that the first 4 characters are `http`.  If the string does not start with `http://` or `https://`  then prepend `http://`

Comment: Thanks Rock. I think you misread my question. I already _do_ the HTML encoding to get around the blacklist (and of course I know that whitelisting is the way to got). What I cannot do using HTML-Encoding is breakt out of the context of the attribute value because if I encode the whole string with html encoding this will not work to add _new_ attributes to the href tag or close the tag since HTML does not decode stuff like &#x6A  into characters outside the context of the attribute value.

Comment: I did not know about the vbscript: handler. Do you know about a good list of handlers that one could try? I did not find the information with OWASP

Comment: It depends on what is installed on the host. Registered protocol handlers are located in the Windows registry under: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PROTOCOLS\Handler`. 

Handler examples: irc, geo, mailto, magnet, mms, news, nntp, sip, sms, smsto, ssh, tel, urn, webcal, xmpp.

Comment: @er4z0r use a whitelist approach,  a blacklist **will always fail**.  You cannot possibly know every bullshit URI,  I could just come up with one right now on my own machine.

Comment: @Rock: Again. This is not about DEFENSE. It is about OFFENSE. I know perfectly well that blacklisting sucks. I want to know if there is a way to gain more than just  execution in the context of href

Comment: @er4z0r  you should read "a tangled web" and close this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can trick someone into clicking on a link like this though:

[Javascript: an_open_source_clientside_scripting_language_commonly_implemented_as_part_of_a_web_browser_in_order_to_create_enhanced_user_interfaces_and_dynamic_websites(); function an_open_source_clientside_scripting_language_commonly_implemented_as_part_of_a_web_browser_in_order_to_create_enhanced_user_interfaces_and_dynamic_websites() {alert(1)}](http://same_url_like_the_url_text.com)

You could try [UTF7 encoding](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#UTF-7_encoding) evasion but is no longer supported in modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. The idea to trick the user into clicking the link like this is ver creative. I like :) The utf-7 approach won't work for me since the target correctly sets the charset to utf-8